# How to integrate RN to an existing iOS project which in separate svn repository

Tags: react-native

I have integrated RN into an existing iOS project successfully, using web tutorials.

But the special case is now our iOS , android , RN projects, which are in a separate svn repository。So we can connect the native iOS and Android projects to the same RN project (the RN project is not inside the root directory of iOS project or the iOS project is not inside the 'ios' directory of the RN project). So in this special case , how can I integrate RN with our iOS project。

Thank you for your help!